# How to read mex.c file in Matlab code

Tags: c, matlab, mex

I have a Matlab code for measurement and when I try to run it this error pops up:

> ```
> Undefined function `mexLoadMeasurements` for input arguments of type `char`.
> Error in LoadMeasurements (line 56)
>   measurements = mexLoadMeasurements(attr.Name);
> ```

I also have the file `measurements_io.mex.c` in my directory, but I don't know how to make it readable for Matlab to run my code.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compile the c file into a mex library (in matlab).

Setup your Matlab's mex compiler:

```
>> mex -setup
```

Compile the c source code

```
>> mex -largeArrayDims -O measurements_io.mex.c -output mexLoadMeasurements
```

Read more about mex files [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/introducing-mex-files.html).